# Why is sass-loader complaining about incompatible units in Bootstrap’s default _variables.scss?

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4, sass, sass-loader

I'm attempting a migration from Bootstrap 3.1.1 to 4.6.0. I haven't made any changes to anything yet and just wanted to see what would happen if I simply swapped in the newer version, but I've hit a roadblock even before getting to see any potential rendering issues.

I'm using webpack and the sass-loader with dart-sass, and getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/sass/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??ref--7-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-3!./src/sass/main.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

$nav-link-height:                   $font-size-base * $line-height-base + $nav-link-padding-y * 2 !default;
                                   ^
      Incompatible units rem and px.
```

The weird thing is that none of those variables are using px.

```
$font-size-base: 1rem !default; // Assumes the browser default, typically 16px

$line-height-base: 1.5 !default;

$nav-link-padding-y: .5rem !default;
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: are you sure those variables weren't overridden somewhere else?

Comment: For me, I found $font-size-base had been declared in a theme I imported and the unit was in px. So that was the cause of the error. Indeed, it was overridden so you need to find that and make appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the rem to px.  1rem = 16px.

Comment: No. Don't convert rem to px, it's irrelevant to OP's issue and disrespects user font settings